# How to use an Interceptor that has parameter in its constructor for Autofac InterceptorSelector

Tags: c#, autofac, system.reflection, castle-dynamicproxy

How can I use an interceptor in IInterceptorSelector.SelectInterceptors method which has a constructor parameter. I want to let Autofac resolve my interceptor with it's parameters something like in this Castle framework:

```
InterceptorReference.ForType<CallLogger>()
```

I make a research about it, but found nothing.

Here is a sample code that taken from examples:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var proxyGenerationOptions = new ProxyGenerationOptions();

        //I want to use this
        //proxyGenerationOptions.Selector = new InterceptorSelector();

        builder.RegisterType<SomeType>()
            .As<ISomeInterface>()
            .EnableInterfaceInterceptors(proxyGenerationOptions)

            .InterceptedBy(typeof(CallLogger));//and remove explicit statement

        builder.Register<TextWriter>(x => Console.Out);

        builder.RegisterType<CallLogger>().AsSelf();

        var container = builder.Build();

        var willBeIntercepted = container.Resolve<ISomeInterface>();
        willBeIntercepted.Work();
    }
}

public class InterceptorSelector : IInterceptorSelector
{
    public IInterceptor[] SelectInterceptors(Type type, MethodInfo method, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
    {
        //don't know how to solve dependency here, because it's registration time
        return new IInterceptor[] { /* new CallLogger(dependency) or InterceptorReference.ForType<CallLogger>()  */};
    }
}

public class CallLogger : IInterceptor
{
    TextWriter _output;

    public CallLogger(TextWriter output)
    {
        _output = output;
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        invocation.Proceed();

        _output.WriteLine("Done: result was {0}.", invocation.ReturnValue);
    }
}

public interface ISomeInterface { void Work(); }

public class SomeType : ISomeInterface { public void Work() { } }
```

I also would like to know, if there is any dynamic interceptor assign mechanism in Autofac. In Castle, there are various ways to modify interception pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Right now this isn't possible in Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy. You can [see in the source](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy/blob/6fb3c7c483f6d2ff0a59e68990e084c414269efe/src/Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy/RegistrationExtensions.cs#L225) that the interceptors are retrieved from a metadata property on the registration (put there by `IntereceptedBy`) and not using the interceptor selector.

We have had [one user note](https://github.com/autofac/Documentation/pull/60) that you can wire up your own interceptors doing something like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<Implementation>().AsSelf();
builder.Register(c =>
{
  ProxyGenerator proxyGen = new ProxyGenerator(true);
  return proxyGen.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTargetInterface<IInterfaceOfImplementation>(
    c.Resolve<Implementation>(),
    c.Resolve<ExceptionCatcherInterceptor>());
}).As<IInterfaceOfImplementation>();
```

This is a bit more manual, but it might get you where you're going.

[I've added an enhancement issue](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy/issues/29) to look into this.

Comment: I appreciate for your help. I will try this. If I understand correctly, the main idea here putting the logic of selector into the Register part. So I can select which interceptors to add inside register.